# controller class naming convention conflict (php)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, naming-conventions

I am building an MVC framework. I am using the PEAR naming convention. Classes have the first letter of each word capitolized.

The problem is when I get to the controller classes. The framework loads the controller based on the URL path. I do not however want to need uppercase letters in my URLs. Is there a common way to deal with this problem?

Comment: `ucfirst()`? Whats the concrete probleme?

Comment: @KingCrunch if the class is more than one word, ucfirst will not conform it to the correct capitol letters. for instance if the controller classes name were PhotoBooth

Comment: You should not have mixed-case filenames in the first place. That's an abhorrent practice by framework designers with no clue about language semantics. Identifiers should behave case-insensitively in PHP.

Comment: @mario so you are saying that new PhotoBooth(); is the same as new photobooth(); in all php builds?

Comment: Yes. `stdClass` is the same as `StDcLaSS` and `strtolower` the same as `STRTOLOWER`. Whether that's a good language design is frequently debated, but PHP still treats them equivalent. (Note that constant names are case-sensitive however. And variables of course.)

Comment: @mario Do you ever find that all lowercase filenames in a project is difficult to read? I am not allowed to use underscores  due to my PSR-0 compliant autoloader. Do you use word separaters of some sort in your file names?

Comment: I do use underscores sometimes. But most of my filenames are compact, as I seldomly follow the 1 class per script scheme. It would be a likely readability issue if you assemble too many includes per directory. That being said, I don't find CamelCase a cure for that.

Comment: @mario: Sorry, but thats horrible practice from developers on windows platforms. Ignoring case-sensitivity is always a good way to produce bugs. Its up to you, if you develop this way, but you really shouldnt recommend it.

Comment: @KingCrunch: I assume the opposite. It's usually Windows coders who are accustomed to mixed-case filenames, use them for PHP, then break the language behaviour by failing to adapt it to the target.

Comment: @mario: There is no problem with mixed-case, especially if it follows a widely adopted standard: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCaps

Comment: @KingCrunch so you agree with the suggested answer? or is there any other ideas I should consider?

Comment: @KingCrunch. There's nothing wrong with it. It's a good indicator for cargo cult programming. Transfusing in-application identifiers onto the filesystem to break the languages case-insensitivity just seems odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fetch the name of the controller from the url (e.g. `/controller/action/id`) and use `ucfirst()` to get the class name of your controller. That's the common way to do it.

Comment: ehhh... and what if your controller class's name is PhotoBooth? you can't just ucfirst() to get the correct cases.

Comment: Then you may want to use the convention that for each uppercase letter you add an underline to the URL. So PhotoBooth would be `photo_booth/action/..`.

Comment: Just as an example: url `/photo-booth` => `implode('', array_map('ucfirst', explode('-', 'photo-booth')))` => class `PhotoBooth`. String conversion is usually not that hard, but a nice playground to be creative :)

Comment: used something similar to king crunches method

Comment: you can use `strtolower()` first 